# PagingToolbar does not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using PagingToolbar to filter my result search, I want do display 20 result per page, but in my grid still display all records.

The bbar in my grid

```
bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', 
store: store,
pageSize: 20,
displayInfo : true,
plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager', {})
}),
```

My Store

```
Ext.define('Mystore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Mymodel',
pageSize: 20,
autoLoad: true,
remoteSort: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'search',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'root',
        idProperty: 'id'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
}
```

});

Anybody could help me ??
Thanks.

Comment: Does your `/search` REST service that provides the data for the store support the `start`, `limit`, and/or `page` parameters needed to support paging?

Comment: No, my controller (back end) method does not support limit, how can I adapt it ? I am using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/search` REST service that provides the data for the store needs to support the `start`, `limit`, and/or `page` parameters so that the store can request a single page of results at a time.

To support the [`limit`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-cfg-limitParam) parameter, your service must limit the number of returned results to no more than the count specified in that parameter.  You'd typically implement that by passing the limit value through to the database query you're using to provide the results.

Comment: But how would I know that when I go to my page will return the next 20, for example, and not give the same 20 previous page?

For example, from 0 to 20 entries after 21 and 40 records not 0 at 20 and after 0-20 again?  I need to follow the order of the records of the database ? Do you understand me?

Comment: That's what the `start` parameter to your service is for.  It identifies the index of the first record to return (e.g. 21 for the second page in your example).

Comment: I found the method `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` in hibernate to limit my search, I am trying to solve yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your Store must contain this parameter with start and limit and your backend need to use these parameters.

baseParams : {
        start:0, limit:20
    }

In java backend,

```
            String startPage = request.getParameter("start");
    String limits = request.getParameter("limit");
```

It's kind of filter for your grid.